# Integrity of a directory in bash

Tags: bash, hash

I found this exercise that my professor proposed in an old exam.

"Write a script in bash that matches a string to a directory passed as a function argument so that running the script on the same directory again makes the string the same if the directory contents have not changed.

So, i thought about compacting the directory into an archive, and extracting its md5 digest. The problem is that if you re-run the script, the digest changes. Why?

I enclose my attempt.

```
  tar -cvzf archive.tgz $1 >> /dev/null;`
  openssl dgst -md5 archive.tgz`
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pathname has relevance

First, make the filename canonical. Otherwise the same directory throws different strings when called with different pathnames. The pathname itself becomes part of *"same"*. Then prof `dir`

```
dir="( readlink -m "$1" )
[[ -d $dir ]] || exit 1
```

Now build a checksum and output the result

```
tar cf - "$dir" | sha1sum | cut -d\  -f1
```

Any compression options like -j slows down the process, but doesn't help. The `cut` command removed the leading filename of `sha1sum`.

## Pathname has no relevance

If the pathname has nor relevance, change the script to:

```
#!/usr/env bash
[[ -d $1 ]] || exit 1
tar cf - -C "$dir" . | sha1sum | cut -d\  -f1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!